# Missunderstanding of Wordpress menus

Tags: menus, navigation

I made my first Wordpress plugin and I have couple questions regarding menus.

When I activate default Wordpress theme "Twenty Fourteen" I can see navigation menu on top of page. My plugin, upon activation, creates some pages, and those pages automatically appear on navigation menu.
I know how to hook into custom menu, but how do hook into this default menu, I would like to filter it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean the [`wp_page_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu) fallback, where you can use the filters `wp_page_menu_args` and `wp_page_menu` to modify it's output.

Notice that this function is a wrapper for the [`wp_list_pages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) function, that ships with the `wp_list_pages_excludes` and the `wp_list_pages` filters.

That function is again wrapper for the [`walk_page_tree()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/walk_page_tree/) function, that activates the [`Walker_Page`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Page) class walker by default. This class extends the `Walker` class.

Here's a little schematic overview:

```
wp_nav_menu()  
     \
      \__ wp_page_menu()   # fallback
              \
               \__ wp_list_pages()
                       \
                        \__ walk_page_tree()
                                 \
                                  \__ new Walker_Page   # default walker
                                            \
                                             \__ extends Walker
```

So there are few ways to modify the output from `wp_page_menu()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it's really helpful